# nanoparticle synthesis by precipitation methods

Tags: nanoparticles

**nano particle synthesis**
Anyone about nano particle synthesis by precipitation methods? what are the different precipitation methods?

Comment: Hi Danish, welcome to the site. I am glad you found it and we hope you stick around to contribute more to our small but growing community. However, this question has a few issues 1) This stack exchange is about modeling or theory of matter not necessarily their preparation 2) it lacks detail and research effort. I hope this helps.

Comment: As Cody mentioned, this site really focuses on computational methods, rather than experimental procedure. This question would probably be better suited for [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com). However, you will need to narrow down and clarify your question or else it would likely be closed as too broad there. If you wind up having a question about *modeling* the process by which nanoparticles form, I would highly encourage you to ask it here.